# How to pass data from parent to child components?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular2-databinding

I have this property in a child component:

```
@Input() submitButtonDisabled: boolean;
```

In the template of my parent component I set it via property binding using interpolation:

```
<my-child-component
  [submitButtonDisabled]="{{disableSubmitButton()}}">
</my-child-component>
```

The child component template reads its
`submitButtonDisabled` property this way:

```
<button id="btSubmit" type="submit" (click)="submit()" 
  [disabled]="submitButtonDisabled">Ok</button>
```

Debugging my typescript code I see property binding working fine, but the submit button keeps disabled no matter what `disableSubmitButton` returns (a boolean value). It seems the component is being rendered before the binding to take place.

Does this make any sense? Where is my mistake?

Reference: [Angular 2 - Component Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

Comment: You've spelt submit with two m's. It looks like you've used it consistently, but just check if you haven't got a different spelling anywhere

Comment: You're right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're passing a **string literal** to your input property, DO NOT USE the square brackets:

```
<my-comp isDisabled="yes"></my-comp>
<my-comp isDisabled="no"></my-comp>
```

In this example, the input property `isDisabled` will contain the string `'yes'` or `'no'`.

If you're passing **anything other than a string literal**, then you MUST use the square brackets:

```
<my-comp [isDisabled]="true"></my-comp>
<my-comp [isDisabled]="false"></my-comp>
<my-comp [isDisabled]="shouldItBeDisabled()"></my-comp>
```

In that example, the input property `isDisabled` will contain the boolean `true` or `false`, or the value returned by the `shouldItBeDisabled()` method.

Notice how NONE of these scenarios uses `{{ ... }}`.

In your case, the problem might be that your method `disableSubmitButton()` doesn't return the correct value. (Also, like Ron537 said, you should drop the `{{ ... }}`.)

Comment: The disableSubmitButton is ok, but you'e right about curly braces. Removing it was enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the double parenthesis from the binding.

Instead of this :

```
[submitButtonDisabled]="{{disableSubmitButton()}}"
```

Use this :

```
[submitButtonDisabled]="disableSubmitButton()"
```

Or this :

```
submitButtonDisabled="{{disableSubmitButton()}}"
```

Comment: First option worked: [submitButtonDisabled]="disableSubmitButton()". The second one did not work. Theses binding are confusing to me. I need to read more about it.